# PHP query strings to be rewritten with htaccess RewriteCond

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a `switch` on `index.php`, which listens to `?action=`

I would like to `rewrite` anything after `index.php/` to `index.php?action=`

Currently I have a rule to remove `index.php`

`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1\.php -f [NC]
 RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ /$1.php [L]`

So a current url looks like;

`localhost:8888/?action=viewBasket`

and would like to rewrite it to;

`localhost:8888/viewBasket`

Im getting confused as to wether I need to create a condition for each switch param, so to prevent images, script, sources etc from being rewritten. Or if there is a condition to check if exisits first. Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have worked it out. Will remove my question tomorrow if no one provides a better soloution.

```
# redirect to any directories
RewriteRule ^styles/(.*) styles/$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^styles/fonts/(.*) styles/fonts/$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^images/(.*) images/$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^bower_components/(.*) bower_components/$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^scripts/(.*) scripts/$1 [L,QSA]

#if not a directory listed above, rewrite the request to ?action=
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?action=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this out :

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?action=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

`RewriteEngine on
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?action=$1 [L]`

First line: Added this because I was scratching my head why it was not working for me. I'm sure you know you need this, just a note for others who might view this.

Second line: Checks if it is not a file.

Third line: Checks if it is not a directory. If it's a file or a directory, it will not process your `RewriteRule`s. By default `RewriteCond`s are operated with and.

Fourth line: I'm sure somebody can write a better rule. [L] last rule, stop evaluating RewriteRules. Tells it to rewrite to index.php?action={whatever} without changing the location header.

The gist of the fourth line is this: if your index.php is

`var_dump($_GET);`

www.example.com/foo

Will yield `array(1) { ["action"]=> string(3) "foo" }`

Comment: @atoms, can you provide what you want to happen if the link is `localhost/styles/foo`? This is addressed to your answer, but I can't comment on your answer, so bear with me